# How to trap a System.Diagnostics.TraceSource's output inside a class library and log its output in MS Unit Test?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, unit-testing, mstest

I have a TraceSource with name "MyLib.Example", but when I create a unit test, it's output doesn't show up in the test result.

I've tried adding a custom TraceListener located inside the test project, and added the app.config to point to the trace listener, I even added the MyLib.dll.config but still nothing.

So how can I capture the output of my TraceSource inside a class library that is being unit tested with MS Unit?

Comment: Why do you need to trace in your unit tests?

Comment: The library being tested emits information that greatly help determining the chain of calls resulting in the failed tests. It is a client library, and some failures only happen during certain combinations of events.

Answer (score 1):

In your app.config you can add a source for the ConsoleListener.  MSTest will pick up anything written to the console and display it in your test output.

```
  <system.diagnostics>
    <sources>
      <source name="MyLib.Example" switchValue="Verbose" >
        <listeners>
          <add name="ConsoleListener" type="System.Diagnostics.ConsoleTraceListener" />
        </listeners>
      </source>
    </sources>
  </system.diagnostics>
```